# How to run an online application rendered inoperable due to Adobe Flash updates?

Tags: web-apps

I ran across [this website](http://www.rustyaxe.com/) today, and being an avid gamer I'm interested in running the online dungeon map editor available [here](http://www.rustyaxe.com/apps/ddo/index.php).

Unfortunately, the developer has stated on his home page that:

> 2/15/2016: Dungeon Demon Online, Endless Empires and Dungeon Brawl were all built using Adobe's Flash programming language. Flash updates have begun to affect programs that run on top of Flash. Those 3 free to use programs are no longer supported but are still available for free public use. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Is there a way to run these applications in spite of the Flash updates? Perhaps uninstall prior updates?

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question like asking (software to run Flash based applications through a web browser) or move it to another SE site - as it's written now, it appears to be off-topic.